# google apps script urlfetch access a site already logged into

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to be able to pull information from a webpage into a spreadsheet using urlfetch. The site that I need to pull the info from requires login information. Once I am logged into that site in one tab on my browser, any subsequent tabs that I open for that site will already be loged on but when I try to acces that site with urlfetch I get an error that says:

"Error in setting cookie. Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here is the code that I am using to try and set the appropriate cookie in the header:

```
function webURL() {

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://website.com");

  var cookie = response.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie']; 
  var header = {'Cookie':cookie};
  var opt3 = {"Headers":header};
  var pageData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pageURL, opt3);


Browser.msgBox(pageData.getContentText());

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that your Google Apps Script code is executed on Google's servers and not on your computer/browser. So, the UrlFetch request is made from Google's servers.

If you know what type of authentication the website uses (HTTP Basic/oauth etc.), then you might be able to have your script perform the authentication.